# Image as byte array does not get visualzied with the 'src' attribute of 'img' element

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core

I have this image that I receive as byte[], but then as I try to display it using the `src` attribute of the `img` element as `data:image/png;base64,[byte array here]` it displays `System.Byte[]` and not the actual array, therefore the image does not get displayed.
Below are two images of my code and the result of it
[image: My code and what I receive in my object that contains the image byte array]

[image: The result of the code]

Comment: There should be the image encoded in base64, not the bytes directly.

Comment: Danke for your time and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the byte array to base64 string. You can use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-6.0) method.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(card.Image)" />
```